# How to send Ec2 logs to S3 and then monitoring it using Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am going through a situation where i do not know which is the correct way and how to do it.

My Aim is :

> ec2 Logs should be uploaded in S3 and logs should be reviewed and
>   monitored using cloudwatch for any unwanted events.

**Scenario 1:**

> 1) Upload ec2 logs to s3 and then to cloudwatch for security review
>   and monitoring

**Scenario 2:**

> 1) Upload ec2 logs to cloudwatch and send data then s3

**Scenario 3:**

> 1) Upload ec2 logs to both s3 and cloudwatch simultaneously

Please help me to achieve what is correct way.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can send the logs to cloudwatch and then use cloudwatch to upload them to S3. Check this solution: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-export-ec2-instance-execution-logs-to-an-s3-bucket-using-cloudwatch-logs-lambda-and-cloudformation/

Comment: Thank you @S.K, i have gone through that link but its using cloud formation. is there any other way instead of using cloud formation ?

Comment: I have now solved half of my task i.e to send logs from Ec2 to Cloudwatch using awslog agent, but wondering how to send logs from cloudwatch to s3 using lambda functions.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html